# Cannot resolve 00 seconds when preparing specific Format of UTC date in Java SE 8 API

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

Code:

```
LocalDateTime ldt3 = getUtcDateTime("2016-02-01T10:11:00Z");
System.out.println(ldt3);
```

Output:

```
2016-02-01T10:11
```

Required Output:

```
2016-02-01T10:11:00
```

Is it possible to derive such a output? Also how to print the UTC String value out of LocalDateTime having zero seconds?

Code:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = getCurrentUtcDateTime();
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("Z"));
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
ZonedDateTime.parse(zonedDateTime.format(formatter), formatter)
                .toString();
```

Output:

```
2016-02-12T12:12Z
```

Required Output:

```
2016-02-12T12:12:00Z
```

How to get the required outputs in both cases?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What you do you want? Do you want to print `2016-02-01T10:11:00`? If so, why are you reparsing what your formatted and not printing the formatted String?

Comment: Refer this guide https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `DateTimeFormatter` to print out your output, instead of reparsing it again. A `LocalDateTime` has no system to store the formatter it was created with.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
System.out.println(zonedDateTime.format(formatter));
```

Comment: But is that really what the OP wants? Apparently, they know how to do this (since they did it in the question).

Comment: From what I can read, the op keeps falling back to using `.toString()` instead of realizing that he need to output the formatted output

Comment: @Ferrybig - Thanks looks like I wrangled myself in the last line